# jquery image-background chrome problem

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

This doesn't seem to work in chrome:

```
$(function(){
$('body').css('background-image','url(/static/img/b1_left.png');
}
```

when I apply it in css it works fine:

```
background-image: url('/static/img/b1_left.png');
```

in firefox both work fine.
I need it to work in jquery, to process hover events (when something is hovered, it and another element has to change background)

Comment: You forgot the right parentheses and quotes. Try adding them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing a parentheses:

```
$(function(){
  $('body').css('background-image','url("/static/img/b1_left.png")');
}
```